# Set state on nested state array -> Error with Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useState storing a the banking object, and after a mutation I need to add the new report onto the nested reports state. I keep getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reports')"

However I am sure this is not undefined as I can see the data returning in the correct format. How am I setting the state incorrectly?

Thanks a lot

```
type BankingObject = {
    reports: BankingReports[];
    loading: boolean;
}

const [bankingObject, setbankingObject] = useState<BankingObject>()

const newReport = useCallback(async() => {
        const { data } = await createBankingReport({ account_id })

        setbankingObject({
            ...bankingObject,
            // reports: bankingObject.reports.concat(data.newBankingReport),
            reports: [...bankingObject.reports, data.newBankingReport],
        })
    }, [])
```

Comment: Initially, the `bankingObject` is empty, because you've not initialized with any value, like empty array etc and destructuring first time causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your useState hook has no default value. So the initial value of bankingObject is undefined. When newReport is called for the first time, bankingObject is still undefined. So `bankingObject.reports` will throw an error.

What you can do is passing an initial value to your state:

```js
const init = {loading: true, reports: []};
const [bankingObject, setbankingObject] = useState<BankingObject>(init)
```